# awk and pattern with slash

Tags: shell-script, awk

Input data contain lines:

```
Network:   10.1.0.0/24          00001010.00000001.00000000. 00000000
Network:   10.1.1.0/24          00001010.00000001.00000001. 00000000
Network:   10.1.2.0/24          00001010.00000001.00000010. 00000000
Network:   10.1.3.0/24          00001010.00000001.00000011. 00000000
Network:   10.1.4.0/24          00001010.00000001.00000100. 00000000
Network:   10.1.5.0/24          00001010.00000001.00000101. 00000000
Network:   10.1.6.0/24          00001010.00000001.00000110. 00000000
Network:   10.1.7.0/24          00001010.00000001.00000111. 00000000
```

I want to use awk to get on output $2 column. What I tried does not return anything:

```
$ ipcalc 10.1.1.0/21 /24|gawk '$1~/^Network:.+\/24[[:space:]]+/{print $2}'
```

When I use the regex with grep, it does work properly:

```
$ ipcalc 10.1.1.0/21 /24|grep -E "^Network:.+\/24[[:space:]]+"
Network:   10.1.0.0/24          00001010.00000001.00000000. 00000000
Network:   10.1.1.0/24          00001010.00000001.00000001. 00000000
Network:   10.1.2.0/24          00001010.00000001.00000010. 00000000
Network:   10.1.3.0/24          00001010.00000001.00000011. 00000000
Network:   10.1.4.0/24          00001010.00000001.00000100. 00000000
Network:   10.1.5.0/24          00001010.00000001.00000101. 00000000
Network:   10.1.6.0/24          00001010.00000001.00000110. 00000000
Network:   10.1.7.0/24          00001010.00000001.00000111. 00000000
```

Do awk (gawk) needs another workaround for this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To emulate your grep command change `$1~` to `$0~` or just remove it:

```
awk '/^Network:.+\/24[[:space:]]+/{print $2}'
```

or make it more robust and portable (for all awks rather than just POSIX awks) with:

```
awk '($1 == "Network:") && ($2 ~ "/24$"){print $2}'
```

The problem with your code was you're testing `$1` for the whole expression but `$1` ONLY contains the first field, i.e. `Network:`.

Answer (score 0):

With your shown samples, please try following GNU `grep` solution. Written and tested with shown samples only.

```bash
grep -oP '^Network:\s+\K([0-9]{1,3}\.){3}[0-9]{1,3}\/24'  Input_file
```